# Debug Assertion Fails When Trying to Write to Log4cpp Stream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash, log4cpp

I'm trying to enable logging with log4cpp in the following way.

```
class Foo
{
    private: 
        log4cpp::Appender* _logAppender;
        log4cpp::Layout* _logAppenderLayout;
}

Foo::Foo()
{
    _logAppender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("foo", "logs/bar.log"));
    _logAppenderLayout = new log4cpp::BasicLayout();
    _logAppender.setLayout(_logAppenderLayout);
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().setPriority(log4cpp::Priority::DEBUG);
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().addAppender(_logAppender);

    // Crash on line below.
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().debugStream() << "test";
}
```

When I get to the line where I try to write "test" to the log, I get a crash that says "Debug Assertion Failed!" The assertion is in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld_self_64_amd64\crt\src\write.c Line 67. The assert that fails is

```
fh >= 0 && (unsigned)fh < (unsigned)_nhandle
```

I have created the logs directory and the bar.log file to make sure it exists. I have also confirmed that both my application and the library were built as 64-bit multithreaded debug DLLs. There was no 64 bit build in the log4cpp source, so I created one based on the 32-bit build configuration. I'm using the latest version of log4cpp.

Comment: Maybe log4cpp needs more than just a configuration change for a 64-bit version. There's a lot of gotchas to worry about with pointer and HANDLE sizes, for example.

Comment: I was thinking that may be the case. I'm looking at other logging frameworks now, but hopefully somebody who has used log4cpp with a 64-bit application sees this.

Comment: To anyone who comes across this question, I wasn't able to get this working. My solution was to move over to google-glog https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/. It doesn't have a built in 64-bit configuration, but it was easy to create.

Answer (score 1):

It is old post, but I guess solution for this problem may be useful for somebody.

Most probably you just **forgot to create directory "logs"** that is in your code.

This is the problem of closed stream: logger does not auto-create directories for your logs, so, no directory -> no file -> open file failed -> invalid file handler -> exception. You should create directories manually. Macros assertions and no more info is sad.

Comment: I manually created the logs directory and the log file to be sure, and still got the crash. No issues in 32 bit. I will be revisiting this issue soon, although I found 64-bit log4cxx binaries that I know work. This means I won't have to figure out what was wrong with my build.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. Probably your problem has another goal, it is strange that we have two equal errors with different causes.Sorry, but whatever I recommend replace "logs/bar.log" with "bar.log" for testing purposes.

Comment: I tried that and got no difference. Also, the way I had it worked fine on the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this question and tried to get this assertion.
I have built log4cpp (ver 1.1) library and **user1229080**'s test for Win32 and x64 platforms in **MSVC2010** and have got no assertion.

I added few lines to get it compiled, and removed "logs" dir from the file path just to get rid of issues related to absent directories:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <log4cpp/Category.hh>
#include <log4cpp/FileAppender.hh>
#include <log4cpp/OstreamAppender.hh>
#include <log4cpp/BasicLayout.hh>

class Foo
{
    private:
        log4cpp::Appender* _logAppender, *_conAppender;
        log4cpp::Layout* _logAppenderLayout;
    public:
        Foo();
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    _conAppender = new log4cpp::OstreamAppender("con", &std::cout);
    _logAppender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("foo", "bar.log");
    _logAppenderLayout = new log4cpp::BasicLayout();
    _logAppender->setLayout(_logAppenderLayout);

    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().setPriority(log4cpp::Priority::DEBUG);
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().addAppender(_logAppender);
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().addAppender(_conAppender);


    // Crash on line below. (but not in msvc2010)
    log4cpp::Category::getRoot().debugStream() << "test" << log4cpp::eol;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo f;

    return 0;
}
```

Which version of visual c++ you encountered the assertion on?